# Python Script doesn´t work when started via other script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I´m currently working on a raspberry pi 4 and wrote a script in python that send a mail with a picture and then rename the file and puts it in another folder.

The script works fine when I start with command

```
sudo python script.py
```

but when start it with another script it won´t execute the part with the renaming

Now the question what is my mistake ?

```
import os
import time
from sendmail import mail
from sendmail import file_rename
from time import sleep

pic = '/home/pi/Monitor/Bewegung.jpg'
movie= '/home/pi/Monitor/Aufnahme.avi'
archiv = '/home/pi/Archiv/'
time = time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')


mail(filename = pic )

file_rename(oldname = pic ,name = 'Serverraum Bild' + time ,format = '.jpg' ,place = archiv )

file_rename(oldname = movie ,name = 'Serverraum Video' + time ,format = '.avi' ,place = archiv )
```

Comment: Hi, which script are you running from where? Can you provide the caller script?

Comment: The script get called by the porgramm motion for the raspberry pi camera via config

Comment: OK can you post that program? Otherwise there is little way to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are starting the script as a user with sudo privileges.

> but when start it with another script it won´t execute the part with the renaming

This makes me suspicious that the caller script does not have the correct permissions to rename/move a file. You can view the permissions of the script with the following command

```
ls -la callerscript.py
```